# requirejs dependencies grouping

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, amd

I am trying to integrate `requirejs` framework to my app.

Is possible to create a **virtual module** (which doesn't exists as a physically file), where i could group all the `jquery-validation` plugins together?

For example, i need to load 4 dependencies everytime i want to use jquery-validate.

Instead of requesting them, each time, i create a **jquery-val** "virtual module", which should request all the dependencies automatically.

However, trying to load "jquery-val" actually tries to load the file from disk (which i don't have).

What should be the best practice in solving this issue?

```
// config
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/Content',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'frameworks/jquery-3.1.1.min',
        "jquery-validate": "frameworks/jquery.validate.min",
        "jquery-validate-unobtrusive": "frameworks/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min",
        "jquery-unobtrusive-ajax": "frameworks/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery-val": ["jquery", "jquery-validate", "jquery-validate-unobtrusive", "jquery-unobtrusive-ajax"]
    }
});


// Solution 1: working, but ugly
define(["jquery", "jquery-validate-unobtrusive", "jquery-unobtrusive-ajax"], function ($) {
    // My Module
});

// Solution 2: not working
define(["jquery-val"], function () {
    // My Module
});

// Solution 3: create jquery-val.js file, which loads the dependencies automatically
// jquery-val.js
(function (global) {
    define(["jquery", "jquery-validate-unobtrusive", "jquery-unobtrusive-ajax"], function ($) {

    });
}(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

take some time and read:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes

> One module per file.: Only one module should be defined per JavaScript file, given the nature of the module name-to-file-path lookup algorithm. You shoud only use the optimization tool to group multiple modules into optimized files.

[Optimization Tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)

To answer your question:
It is good practice to define **one module per file**, so you don't need to define explicit a name for the module AND do the need for inserting it somewhere to be available before the other modules are loaded.

So you could require just the file: require("../services/myGroupModule") and this file would hold your module and requireJS would take care of the loading dependencies (and later the optimizations for concatenating into one file!). Here the module name is the file name.

You could nevertheless do the following and loading it as a file module or like you tried to define it beforehand and give the module a name:

```
//Explicitly defines the "foo/title" module:
define("myGroupModule",
    ["dependency1", "dependency2"],
    function(dependency1, dependency2) {
        return function myGroupModule {
            return {
                doSomething: function () { console.log("hey"); }
            }
        }
   }
);
```

Maybe you should also give a look at some new module loaders:

WebPack 2: https://webpack.js.org/

SystemJS: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs